# Ajax dojo request locking browser big json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dojo

I have a big json data about 40000 item. When I send request to get all, browser is locked process until responce come.
So I am sending request by **index** and **chunk** like following.

```
        var index = 0;
        var chunk = 500;
        var repeat = true;

        document.getElementById('loading').style.display='inline-block';

        while (repeat == true) {
            var requestOptions = {
                handleAs: "json",
                sync: true,
                query: {
                    page: index,
                    chunk: chunk
                },
            };
            request.get("domain.com/getdata", requestOptions).then(
                function(response) {
                    array.forEach(response.data, function(item) {
                        //do something
                    });

                    if (response.data.length < chunk) {
                        repeat = false;
                        document.getElementById('loading').style.display='inline-block';

                    }

                    index = index + 1;
                },
                function(error) {
                    repeat = false;
                }
            );
        }
```

I am sending request to get first 500 record. Than get secont 500 record...
When I sart process, the browser locking. I want to Show loading request but not appearing.

Comment: `sync: true,` ... use an asynchronous approach instead.

Comment: is it locking up while processing `//do something` or retrieving?

Comment: Did you try with Workers?

Comment: Sync:false is sending request witout one response come. Always sending same request parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I see in the comments on your question that you've been recommended to use `async:true`, to which you respond that it is sending requests without getting any response, and always sending the same request parameters.

I think then that you're perhaps a bit unfamiliar with the **asynchronous** paradigm in Javascript (remember, Ajax means **asynchronous** Javascript and XML).

First off: async:true *is* the right way to solve your problem. However, as you've noticed, that alone doesn't fix anything in your code.

Here's a simplified and modified version of your code (don't try this, it doesn't work, it's for explanation purposes only).

```
    var index = 0;
    var chunk = 500;
    var repeat = true;

    while (repeat == true) {
        var requestOptions = {
            handleAs: "json",
            sync: false, // false is default, so this line is redundant
            query: { page: index, chunk: chunk },
        };
        request.get("domain.com/getdata", requestOptions).then(
            responseOk, responseError);
    }

    function responseOk(response) {
        //do something..

        if (response.data.length < chunk) {
            repeat = false;
        }
        index = index + 1;
    }

    function responseError(error) {
        repeat = false;
    }
```

Here's the kicker: the ´responseOk´ function is **never** run. Therefore, `index` is never updated, and `repeat` is never set to false - in effect making your while loop infinite!

Why is this? The reason is that Javascript's "Ajax" functions (which are wrapped by dojo's `request.get()` and friends) are **asynchronous**.

What you are saying in your code (or rather, in my simplified version above) is effectively:

> Hey, Javascript, do a GET request to the server. When you are done,
>   sometime in the future, run this responseOk function (or responseError
>   on error). In the mean time, **while** you are doing that, I'll
>   continue with my while loop.

So the while loop keeps churning out GET requests to the server, with the same index! Since the neverending loop is keeping your Javascript thread busy (you only have one!), the responseOk function isn't allowed to execute (even though the server may have responded).

That said, how can you split your huge JSON array into multiple, subsequent requests?

You can try something like this:

```
var index = 0,
    chunk = 500,
    requestOptions = {....};

function handleResponseAndGetNextChunk(response) {

    response && array.forEach(response.data, function(item) {
        //do something
    });
    if(response && response.data.length < chunk) {
        return;
    } else {
        requestOptions.page = index++;
        request.get("domain.com/getdata", requestOptions).then(
            handleResponseAndGetNextChunk, responseError);
    }

}

// To start off the sequence of requests:
handleResponseAndGetNextChunk(null);
```